# confusion in relation of linear map and $F[x]$-module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $F$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$ a linear map.

Then $V$ is an $F[x]$-module in which $x$ acts by $T$.

**Q.** Is $V$, as $F[x]$-module, isomorphic to a quotient of module $F[x]$?

I thought, if $m_T(x)$ is minimal polynomial of $T$ then $V\cong F[x]/(m_T(x))$ as $F[x]$-module. But, as vector spaces they may have different dimensions; the dimension of $F[x]/(m_T(x))$ is degree of $m_T(x)$, which can be smaller than dimension of $V$. This created confusion. How should I proceed?

For example, take $T$ to be identity and $V$ of dimension $10$. Then $m_T(x)=x-1$ and $F[x]/(m_T(x))\cong F$, which is one dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain, we have that
$$
V \cong F[x]\big/(a_1)\oplus\dotsb\oplus F[x]\big/(a_m)
$$
both as an $F$-vector space and as an $F[x]$-module for $a_i\in F[x]$ and $a_1\mid \dots \mid a_m$ in $F[x]$. In fact, the minimal polynomial of $T$ is precisely $a_m$.

So the answer to your question is no, in general. However, $V$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of finitely many quotients of $F[x]$.

As a consequence, $V$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $F[x]$ if and only if the minimal polynomial of $T$ is irreducible.

Comment: This makes something clarity now; thanks for stating it. I will think again.

Comment: Isn't that minimal polynomial is always irreducible? Should it be characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @edm No the minimal polynomial is not always irreducible. Consider for instance $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ over $\mathbb Q$. The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $m_A(x) = (x-2)(x-3)$. The characteristic polynomial is the product of all of the $a_i$: $a_1a_2\dotsb a_m$.

Comment: @AOrtiz I guess I confused with minimal polynomial in field extension sense. Is the existence of reducible minimal polynomial in linear algebra sense related to existence of zero divisors?

Comment: @edm If $F$ is a field, then $F$ has no zero divisors. I'm not sure if that answers your question.